# Does any function likes 'Lpad | Rpad' but supports regular expression? In Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a column named date_list, it's value likes below:

```
2014-04-11,2014-04-11,2014-04-14,2014-04-17
2014-04-13,2014-04-15,2014-04-17
```

You can see that one has four elements and another has three, but now I want to keep it five elements. I need concat ',Nil' if it's elements less than five.
So the result I expect is:

```
2014-04-11,2014-04-11,2014-04-14,2014-04-17,Nil
2014-04-13,2014-04-15,2014-04-17,Nil,Nil
```

Here is my method,but it is uncertain about the count of elements:
`decode(REGEXP_COUNT(date_list,','),2,date_list||',Nil,Nil',3,date_list||',Nil',date_list)`

Any advice appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
replace( rpad( date_list,length(date_list) + 4-REGEXP_COUNT(date_list,','), '@' ), 
         '@', ',nil' )
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a24ca

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
decode(
REGEXP_COUNT (cadena,',',1,'i'),
1,cadena || ',nil,nil,nil',
2,cadena || ',nil,nil',
3,cadena || ',nil',
cadena) resultado  FROM demo2;
```